# Déja Dup backup error message

Tags: deja-dup, error-handling

I just started using Ubuntu 14.04 from yesterday. As till now the system is running pretty smooth. Although when trying to do a backup I got the following error-message:

*Could not backup the following files. Please make sure you are able to open them.
/home/bram/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg*

anyone knows how to fix this?

update: the concerning file (it's not possible to add printscreen due to low reputation) has root rights. Does anybody have an idea why?
Is it possible to change and maybe more important, is it usefull to change?
As long is I can use my backups I'm a happy man.

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: If so, is it readable by your username?

Comment: dear daniel, thanks for your reply. actually i have no idea if this file exists. is there any way i can check this? thx

Comment: give the output of running 'ls -l /home/bram/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg' in Terminal

Comment: thx for the reply daniel but unfortunately did not do the job...

Comment: the command can not do the job. It is just for checking whether the file exists. if that is the case the output should be like `file oder directory not found`

Comment: update: the concerning file (it's not possible to add printscreen due to low reputation) has root rights. Does anybody have an idea why? Is it possible to change and maybe more important, is it usefull to change? As long is I can use my backups I'm a happy man.

Comment: output of the running you adviced earlier is:
bram@lapto-bram:~$ ls -l /home/bram/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
-rw------- 1 root root 1200 Jul 17 23:22 /home/bram/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg

Comment: Ah, so see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in Terminal (you will be asked for your password)

```
sudo chown -R bram:bram /home/bram/.gnupg/
```

Comment: thx daniel, this did the job for me. I was able to do my first succesfull backup using Déja Dup.